# I want to delete a SQL db. How can I tell if it is being used?

Tags: sql-server

I have W2k3 SBS running SQL 2005.
I want to delete a SQL db.  How can I tell if it is being used?

Thanks.

Comment: Being used at that moment in time, or has been used in lats xx period?

Comment: Take it offline in the middle of the business day and listen where the screams and yells come from - if any :-)

Comment: Sorry.  I should've been more forthcoming with the info.  I've been given the go ahead to delete the db, but being on the cautious side, I wanted to make sure no one else is using it.

So marc_s, great idea.  I detached the db.  I'll give it a month and if I don't hear any screams from anyone.  Away it goes.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
select db_name(dbid) [database],T0.* from master..sysprocesses T0 WHERE  db_name(dbid)='your database'
```

To see users and process connected to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You let the server run for long enough to catch any activity, then you look into the `last_user_xxx` columns in [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) for tables in your database. Any SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on any table during the lifetime of a server process will leave its imprint on those columns.